# brackets. code hint does not work with namespaced objetcs?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I have namespaced objects.

```
AAA ={}
AAA.TWO = {}
AAA.TWO.obj = function () {}
....
var aaa = new AAA.TWO.obj()
```

Ok, I think this is a problem. Brackets does not work with namespaced object instances or maybe this is a bug ?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what's not working or what you expected to happen? If I start typing the last line in Brackets the code hints seem to work fine. E.g. if I type `var aaa = new AAA.` I will get a code hint for "TWO" and then after the next dot I'll get a code hint for "obj"...

Comment: @peterflynn Thanks for your answer. The problem is that behaviour works fine in a limited scope. That is, if you create the object instance 'aaa' as a private var inside another object BBB (for example), inside BBB.bbb_function() {aaa. } offer you a mix of all public-global functions and AAA, AAA.TWO , AAA.TWO.obj, functions... And then, it is not usefull at all the dot code hint. I hope now the problem is understandable.